# Geometry Node: Aligning Text With Edge (Vector)

Tags: geometry-nodes, vector

I am trying to align text with one edge of a plane using Geometry Nodes. The solution seems to be working but when I rotate the edge the text rotates in a strange way. Rotating the edge around Z doesn't rotate the text at all.

[image: Out of Sync Text Rotation]

Here's the node setup
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this task you need two direction vectors:

- The normal of the face
- The *X* or *Y* direction in which the face points

You can easily get the normals with `Transfer Attributes`.

You can calculate the orientation of the face on the other axes by selecting only one edge, calculating the direction vector between the points of this edge, and using this for another rotation with `Align Euler to Vector`.

Something like this:

[image]

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.2+)*</sub>

Comment: Amazing! Thank you very much. If I have a mesh line instead of a plane, would it be possible to align the text to that line without having face normal?

Comment: Of course you can also use a mesh line as a base. But then you need an additional vector, which describes in which direction the text should point. You can also define this vector manually (for example $(0,0,1)$).

Comment: @quellenform when you delete geometry that's not index 0, is that to just leave one edge? Also how do you know which edge is 0? Thank you.